# Remove all the events attached to an element except one

Tags: javascript, jquery

How may I remove all the events attached to a DOM element except one using jquery?

For example, I have a drop down `<select>` and it has various events attached to it (say click, double click, change etc). What I want to achieve is to just have `change` event applied to it and remove all the other events. How may I achieve this?

**P.S** I don't know about the events attached to the element

Comment: Were all of the event handlers attached using jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#foo").unbind( "click" );
```

Fill in the rest. http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: If they were adding the event handlers themselves, and therefore knew exactly what types needed to be removed, they could just, you know, *not* add them if they don't actually want them. Seems reasonable to think that they want to remove an arbitrary and unknown set of event types from a given element.

Comment: It is not about the handlers, but the event itself. Lets say you have a button that you can click. With my example you can remove the click event. Now the button is just a plain element that does nothing (if the click event could be triggered, you would see an event to that UI type). So its more a visual thing, rather than code handling.

Comment: That's totally incorrect. jQuery is used for registering event *handlers* - code that executes when an event of the given type is registered by that element (or an element within it for events that propagate). The jQuery `unbind` function removes event handlers *that were added using jQuery* from that element, but events of that type are still registered; your button is still a button that can be clicked if you call `.unbind('click');` on it; that click just won't execute any additional code you've said should run using jQuery when that happens.

Comment: If you want to make it unclickable you actually have to **add** an event handler that suppresses the default behaviour (e.g. submitting a form or following a link).

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#foo").off();
```

Will remove all events attached to foo element

You can also do:

```
 $( "#foo").off("click dblclick");
```

you can then attach on foo element only onchange event

```
$("#foo").on("change",function(){
   //Do stuff here
})
```

Comment: They don't want to remove *all* events, they want to remove all except for a specific type.

Comment: @Ricky please read the question first. I don't want to remove all the events.

Comment: @Kamran Ahmed You can remove all the events from an element if you don't know how many there are and then attach only the one you want

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use something like:

```
$.(selector).on('*',function(e)
{
 if(e.which='value_for_your_event_eg._14_for_tab')
 return true;
 else
 return false;
})
```

I don't know, I'm not an expert, but I guess this would work.

Answer (score 0):

`$._data(elem,'events')` is not a method publicly supported:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sLeBm/)

```
$.each($._data($('select').get(0),'events'),function(k){
    if(k !== "change")
        delete $._data($('select').get(0),'events')[k];
});
```